# How to unregister a COM interop DLL?

Tags: .net, com, interop

To register im using following command in `VS CMD`

```
regasm someDll.dll /someDll.tlb
```

however when i try to **unregister**:

```
regasm /u someDll.dll
```

the `someDll.dll` is till accessible even tho the CMD writes `Types un-registered **successfully**`

How can i unregister a dll?

Comment: You might need to unregister the typelib as well: `regasm someDll.dll /tlb /unregister`. Or try to re-register the dll with the `codebase` option

Comment: Make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fully remove a COM server from your system, you also need to unregister its type library: `regasm someDll.dll /tlb /unregister`.

Note that you can ease the registration process on development machines by using regasm's `codebase` option. This avoids the hassle of having to deal with the GAC and multiple assembly versions of your DLL. You can ignore the warning about a missing signature when using this approach.